# Apply a method to all fileds of a case class of a specific type

Tags: scala, generics, design-patterns

I'll give an example/motivation for what I'm trying to do.

Imagine I have a Money case class, and a way to convert it's value from one currency to another:

```
case class Money(currency: String, amount: BigDecimal) {
  def convert(date: LocalDate)(using cc: CurrencyConverter): Money = {...}
}
```

The `CurrencyConverter` is a Map with daily exchange rates between currency, so that I can use the `convert` method to go for example from something like `Money("EUR", BigDecimal(100))` to `Money("USD", BigDecimal(114.13))`.

Then, I have a lot of different case classes with one or more Money fields. For example:

```
case class House(date: LocalDate, price: Money, city: String)

case class MarketData(
    exchange: String,
    ticker: String,
    date: LocalDate,
    closingPrice: Money,
    openPrice: Money
)
```

Since I could data where the data is in a lot of different currencies, for example

```
val house1 = House(LocalDate.parse("2010-01-01"), Money("USD", BigDecimal(400000)), "San Francisco")
val house2 = House(LocalDate.parse("2018-01-01"), Money("EUR", BigDecimal(200000)), "Rome")
```

it would be useful to give each case class a method `convertCurrency` to allow them to convert their Money fields to a common currency.

I could define a trait with an abstract method and manually override it inside each case class definition, like so:

```
trait MoneyConverter[A] {
  def convertCurrency(using cc: CurrencyConverter): A
}

case class House(date: LocalDate, price: Money, city: String)
  extends MoneyConverter[House] {
  override def convertCurrency(using cc: CurrencyConverter): House =
    House(date, price.convert(date), city)
}

case class MarketData(
                       exchange: String,
                       ticker: String,
                       date: LocalDate,
                       closingPrice: Money,
                       openPrice: Money
                     ) extends MoneyConverter[MarketData] {
  override def convertCurrency(using cc: CurrencyConverter): MarketData =
    MarketData(
      exchange,
      ticker,
      date,
      closingPrice.convert(date),
      openPrice.convert(date)
    )
}
```

but it seams like I'm repeating myself. Each method is doing basically the same: it is applying the convert method to each `Money` field, and leaving the other fields as they were.

So my question is: Is there a way for me to describe this behavior for a generic class `A`, so that I can then just extend the `MoneyConverter` trait, without having to manually override the `convertCurrency` method for each case class?

Comment: Probably yes but you will just increase the level of complexity and cognitive load of your code for little gain. Rather, I would rather use a typeclass like this: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/GTsI0mltSk2Emg6vCqMwnw/4 You save a little bit of the boilerplate and is more flexible since you don't need to modify the types to extend this interface. - PS: I would also consider using an `enum` for `currency` instead of a plain `String`

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the code! I'm a little bit confused about the advantage of this approach compared to the extension of the MoneyConverter trait. I still need to code a separate method for each case class, right? In one case I override it in the class and in the other I do that as a given of each companion object. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Yeah, as I said my intention was not to reduce the boilerplate. Rather, provide a solution more flexible and type safe than inheritance and then see how to reduce the boilerplate.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you are approaching it from a wrong direction, and that's the root of your problem. Why bother to covert everything ahead of time, without even knowing if you are ever going to need the result (maybe you are only interested in closing price to begin with, so why bother converting the other values)?

Rather that `convert(date)(using cc): Money` just create
`get(date)(cc): BigDecimal`. This way, you can carry your `Money` fields around in the "canonical" form, and convert them on demand to whatever currency you need at the call site.

Comment: Thanks for the input! You make a valid point, but I still see some value in being able to homogenize the currencies early on (for example right after loading a dataset) and then forgetting about it, instead of having to remember to do the conversion each time I'm doing any operation involving Money values.

Comment: Just make `amount` private, then you won't need to "remember to do the conversion": `get` will be the only way you can access the value.